# Installing OpenVZ inside debian 6.0?

Tags: debian, openvz

I have a little problem. Basically I have dealt with a VPS for quite a while and decided to make the jump to a more powerful dedicated machine, and then split that into various VPS' for different purposes that I need.

Now I was told tonight by my friend that I shouldn't install OpenVZ inside Debian as it'll be a lot slower. I have no knowledge of this stuff, but is he correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The performance impact of OpenVZ should be minimal (see for instance [this study](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2007/HPL-2007-59R1.html?jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN)). However, OpenVZ has the disadvantage that it cannot host other operating systems. Therefore I'd prefer KVM or VirtualBox over OpenVZ.

Comment: Oh right thank you! Will KVM or Virtual box be the same in terms of performance impact?

Comment: No. OpenVZ has some advantages performance-wise, because it doesn't emulate an entire machine, but for the same reason it is limited OS-wise. KVM and VirtualBox are real hypervisors, so they can run (virtually) any operating system, but the virtualization layer needs some more system resources than OpenVZ containers. The impact isn't too hard, though. My desktop system is a single core Athlon64 3700+ with 4 GB RAM, and I can run my desktop and 2-3 VirtualBox-VMs without problems.